# Can I write an Equation on a HTML button?

Tags: html, css

Apart from using image on the button, how can I write X<sup>Y</sup> on the HTML button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>Assuming you mean X<sup>Y</sup> then</del> `<button>X<sup>Y</sup></button>`

<del>If you were being literal, then `<button>X^Y</button>`</del>